# Why do we differ between copy and direct initialization?

Tags: c++, initialization, copy-constructor, copy-initialization

I have following questions and I hope you can help me. 
Code:

```
A a; //A(void) is called
A b(a); //A(const A&) is called: direct-initialization
A c = a; //A(const A&) is called: copy-initialization
```

Why are we differ between these initializations?

```
1) A b(a);
2) A c = a;
```

I think in this case both are the same, because each time the copy-constructor is called.
Or are we differ because a implicit conversion could be possible in 2)?

But I read that also in this case we differ between the initializations:

```
3)  int a(5);
4)  int a = 5;
```

Why are these different initializations?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: there are the same: using assignment operator while constructing an abject will call the ctor  non-zero argument. however you cannot write: `A a = ()` for default ctor

Comment: @Raindrop7 They aren't exactly the same, and that is what this question is about.

Comment: @juanchopanza: explain then the difference I'd like to know